# Expose metrics for Kotlin using JMX_Exporter to prometheus

Tags: docker, kotlin, openshift, grafana, prometheus

I am trying to use JMX_Exporter for my kotlin code to expose metrics to prometheus in order to show it in Grafana. I have gone through many articles and tried to understand how could it be done. I have found below two links useful and trying to achieve using those.

1. https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter
2. https://www.openlogic.com/blog/monitoring-java-applications-prometheus-and-grafana-part-1

What i did so far is, created a folder 'prometheus-jmx' in root directory and added mentioned JAR and config.yml file in that folder. Then, i added below parameter to my dockerfile.

```
CMD java -Xms128m -Xmx256m -javaagent:./jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.12.0.jar=8080:./config.yml -Dconfig.file=config/routing.conf -cp jagathe-jar-with- 
    dependencies.jar:./* com.bmw.otd.agathe.AppKt
```

My prometheus is running in my OpenShift cluster along with my application. I could scrape metrics for my other applications/deployments like Jenkins, SonarQube etc without any modifications in deployment.yml of Prometheus.

My application is running properly now on OpenShift and from application's pod, I can scrape metrics by using below command.

```
curl http://localhost:portNumber
```

But on promethus UI, I cant see any JVM or JMX related metric.

Can someone please tell me where and what am i doing wrong? Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you see any error logs in Kotlin? did the server correctly listining to 8080 ? is the path under root is accessible from Kotlin ?

Comment: @LinPy Yeah, path is accessible from Kotlin because when I package my code, everything which I want to copy on OpenShift pod gets copied. I am not sure about port because I don't know what should I put as port because everything is running on openshift cluster. Maybe i need to put url so that i can get metrics. But I am not sure..

Comment: for sure the port should be accessible to work

Comment: @LinPy I dont understand.. :-(

Comment: @LinPy do i need to add some maven dependencies for prometheus?

Comment: @misiek do you have any idea about it?

Comment: @LinPy..You were right. I gave incorrect path. I changed it and now I can scrape metrics from my application's pod on OpenShift but not from promethus UI..

Answer (score 0):

After trying many things, I came to know that I needed to expose the port of my application's container in order to let Prometheus or other deployments to know. After exposing the port, I could see my application under targets on Prometheus and I could scrape all JMX and JVM metrics. Hope this would help someone in future...